# How to log the results of pytest into multiple log files based on each test

Tags: python, pytest

I have multiple tests that would run using pytest and I want to have a separate log for each test. How i would do that?
The solution I have now is like this:

```python
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def write_logs(request):
    # put logs in tests/logs
    log_path = pathlib.Path(ROOT_DIR) / "tests_logs"

    # tidy logs in subdirectories based on test module and class names
    module = request.module
    class_ = request.cls
    name = request.node.name + ".log"

    if module:
        log_path /= f"{module.__name__.replace('tests.', '')}_logs"
    if class_:
        log_path /= class_.__name__

    log_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # append last part of the name
    log_path /= name

    # enable the logger
    logger.remove()
    fmt = "[{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss}][{level}] - {message}"
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    logger.configure(handlers=[{"sink": log_path, "level": "INFO", "mode": "w", "format": fmt}, {"sink": sys.stdout, "level": "INFO", "format": fmt}])
    logger.add(log_path, format=fmt, filter="my_module", level="INFO")
    logger.add(sys.stderr, format=fmt, filter="my_module", level="INFO")
    logger.enable("my_package")
```

but this won't include the pytest failure messages and I need them to be included in the log

Comment: [`pytest-logger`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-logger/) claims to have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

can suggest one way with loguru

create fixture for every test in conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def logger(request):
    yield Logger().create_test_logger(request)
```

Define logger class

```
import loguru

STDOUT_FORMAT = ("{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS} | <level>{level}</level> | "
                 "{name}:{function}:{line} | <level>{message}</level>")

class Logger:
    logger = None

    def __init__(self):
        loguru.logger.remove()
        self.logger = loguru.logger.bind(name='Common logger')
        self.logger.add(sys.stdout, level='INFO',
                        filter=stdout_filter, format=STDOUT_FORMAT, enqueue=True)

    def create_test_logger(self, test):
        test_name = test.node.name
        _, test_log_path = get_test_path(test.node, 'test-debug.log')
        test_logger = loguru.logger.bind(name=test_name)
        test_logger.add(test_log_path, format=STDOUT_FORMAT, filter=lambda record: record["extra"].get("name") == test_name)
```

for get_test_path i'm using such def, you can implement your definition

```
def get_test_path(test_item, filename: str):
    module_path = Path(test_item.location[0]).with_suffix('').parts[1:]
    test_name = f'{test_item.name.replace("/", "_")}'
    result_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'reports', *module_path, test_name)
    result_path = os.path.join(result_dir, filename)
    return result_dir, result_path
```

Use in tests as fixture:

```
class TestClass:

    def test_1(self, logger):
        logger.info('test_1')

    def test_2(self, logger):
        logger.info('test_2')
```

[image: logs]